# HTTP Request in Python TypeError

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Why does this code return exception:

```
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.class.name} 
TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable
```

My code:

```
import requests

json_data  = {"Челябинская обл, г Челябинск, ул Ворошилова, д 55"}
resp = requests.post('https://dadata.ru/api/v2/suggest/address', json=json_data)
resp.json()

print(resp.json()[0]['region_fias_id'])
```

Comment: Sets can not be converted to JSON. Do you want to have a list or dictionary instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it says, your `json_data` variable is a set.

According to the [docs of the API you are using](https://dadata.ru/api/suggest/address/), it looks like you need a dict with a "query" key:

```
json_data  = {"query": "Челябинская обл, г Челябинск, ул Ворошилова, д 55"}
```

Although also note you'll need to include your API key in the headers of that post:

```
headers = {"Authorization": "Token {}".format(API_KEY)}
resp = requests.post('https://dadata.ru/api/v2/suggest/address', json=json_data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, could you tell, how to paste API key in this reqeuest?